# Theme options: Display ID of page options

Tags: theme-options, settings-api

I am building a theme options page and everything is great.

There is a function to display the list of page options.

```
$all_pages = get_pages();
$page_options = array();
$page_list = array();
$page_list_footer = array();
$checked_options = array();

foreach ($all_pages as $page){
    $page_list[] = "acera_nav_header_".$page->ID;
    $page_list_footer[] = "acera_nav_footer_".$page->ID;
    $page_title = get_page($page->ID);
    $page_options[] = $page_title->post_title;
    $checked_options[] = "not";
}
```

This is the option:

```
array( 
"under_section" => "Pages",
"name" => "Pages",
"desc" => "",
"id" => "anything",
"type" => "select",
"options" => $page_options,
"tip" => ""),
```

This is the front end code to display the selected page.

```
<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('anything'))  ?>
```

Everything is working just fine, but the problem is that I want to display the name of the page in the admin back end, and to display the ID of the selected page in front end.

This way , it displays the name of the page in front end. How can I display the ID instead.

Please if there is any solution or tweaks I can do for this, help me, I would be so thankful.
Thanks

Comment: Where is the code that actually displays on the front end? You've built set some variables and built some arrays but I don't see anything that `echo`s content.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have added the options and the function to call it in front end.
Everything is working fine, The page name is displayed in the front end, but I want to display the ID.. so the fix must be done in the function itself.

Comment: Post all of your theme options code please.

Comment: I use acera theme options, It's too much of code.

Comment: What is `var_dump(get_option('page_id'));`? I am puzzled why something called `page_id` prints the page name.

Comment: I have posted the code that should be modified. the first function is the one responsible to display the list of pages. and it displays the page name properly, I need to display the ID instead, by keeping the name of pages in the backend ( as it is now). Thanks

Comment: There is no var_dump(get_option('page_id')); if you mean echo stripslashes(get_option('page_id'))  , I use this to display the name of the selected page. it works fine.

Comment: No. I meant `var_dump(get_option('page_id'));`. Add that to the page and tell me what it is. You have posted the code that _you think_ should be modified, but something is missing. And doesn't it seem odd to you that an option named `page_id` would print the page _name_?

Comment: I am sorry, the page_id is just an ID to give to that option I changed it to page_option.

Comment: The Id of the option can be called anything, I set page_id because my intention was to display the ID. but to make my question clear, I changed it to page_option, or it can be anything else.

Comment: In the code above, where do you set the `page_id` option? I should note that this question has become quite frustrating. I don't think you've given a direct answer to a single thing I've asked so far. If you can't provide the information I ask for this will be my last attempt to help.

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum. please if you look at the code above I edited it, there is no page_id anymore.. it was just an id for the option itself, not to call the id of the page.. now I renamed it and it's still working. please look at the code again, You'll see no page_id anymore. Thanks for your help.